# DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer ignores custom input (aws lambda net6)

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

Following the documentation for aws lambda net6:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html
- or small tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/

The simple Top-level lambda code below ignores my simple POST request. The console displays `>;0`. Why ? Did I forget a package?

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
var handler = async (LambdaInput input, ILambdaContext context) =>
{
    Console.Write($">{input.Property1};{input.Property2}");
}

await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer())
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();
```

```
public class LambdaInput
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; } = "";
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

The `test.http`

```
POST https://my.api.com/request
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Property1": "Simple text",
    "Property2": 8612
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question and answer here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1227
by @normj

You are writing a Lambda function that listens to API Gateway's HTTP events. The event type for those Lambda functions is Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents and should be your first parameter in your function. That event object represents all of the parts of an HTTP request including headers, resource and request body. In your example you can take Body property and serialize into LambdaInput.

You might be interested in checking this new library we are working on that removes some of this complexity into a pattern you might be more use to.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-net-annotations-lambda-framework-preview/